ActiveAdmin has_many helper is only displaying one record
I have a very strange situation in my app where one use of ActiveAdmin's form.has_many helper is working as expected, and a new near-copy of it is only showing the last record in the list.
Here's my AA code:
  form do |f|
    # ...
    unless resource.practices.blank?
      panel "Practices" do
        f.inputs do
          f.has_many :practices, sortable: :position, sortable_start: 0, allow_destroy: true, new_record: false, heading: false do |t|
            t.input :title, input_html: {readonly: true}
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

In spite of there being three practises, only one is showing up on the form:

Here's my models:
class PracticeCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :practices
  #...
end

class Practice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :practice_category

  delegate :course, to: :practice_category
end

Things I've tried:

Selecting all Practices while debuggging the form (3 returned)
Changing the relations to order practises both ascending and descending
Debugging in the has_many block. (It is only called once)
Googling (I can't see any record of anyone else having a similar problem)

It looks fine, but for some reason it's only acting on the most recent child record.
Using Activeadmin 3.2.2 on rails 7.1.3

Finally found it, and honestly I'm surprised that more people aren't running into this problem. So I'm answering my own question to leave some breadcrumbs.
This was only rendering one record when accepts_nested_attributes_for is missing from the model
class PracticeCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :practices, -> { order(position: :asc) }

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :practices

Now the form is rendering a section for each record, as expected.
There are no errors or warnings that I'm aware of to signpost this issue.
